# Very low frame rate during the login screen of Ubuntu LTS 20.01.1

Tags: ubuntu, login, graphic-card

I installed Ubuntu Dekstop 20.04.1 LTS for x64 systems on a old HP Proliant ML110 G5. It works quite well since it recognizes the tape drive and the embedded SATA raid controller, but during the login screen the system is very very laggy; however after I logged in, the system works well and it is smooth. This is not a great issue, but it's very annoying and I would like to know to fix it.
The output of *lspci* command is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation
3200/3210 Chipset DRAM Controller (rev
01) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel
Corporation 3200/3210 Chipset
Host-Primary PCI Express Bridge (rev
01) 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB
UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) 00:1a.1
USB controller: Intel Corporation
82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI
Controller #5 (rev 02) 00:1a.2 USB
controller: Intel Corporation 82801I
(ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
(rev 02) 00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2
EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) 00:1c.0
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I
(ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev
02) 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI
Express Port 5 (rev 02) 00:1c.5 PCI
bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9
Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB
UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) 00:1d.1
USB controller: Intel Corporation
82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI
Controller #2 (rev 02) 00:1d.2 USB
controller: Intel Corporation 82801I
(ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
(rev 02) 00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2
EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) 00:1e.0
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801
PCI Bridge (rev 92) 00:1f.0 ISA
bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IR
(ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller (rev
02) 00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel
Corporation SATA Controller [RAID
mode] (rev 02) 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel
Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus
Controller (rev 02) 00:1f.5 IDE
interface: Intel Corporation 82801I
(ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Controller
[IDE mode] (rev 02) 05:00.0 PCI
bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8114
PCI Express-to-PCI/PCI-X Bridge (rev
bc) 06:08.0 SCSI storage controller:
Broadcom / LSI 53c1030 PCI-X
Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev c1)
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller:
Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA
G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1)
(rev 02) 0e:00.0 Ethernet controller:
Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI
Express
```

The output of *journalctl -b -p err è* command is:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-11-13 12:49:51 CET, end at Fri 2020-11-13
21:26:44 CET. -- nov 13 21:22:54
server kernel: ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected
SPCR Access Width. Defaulting to byte
size nov 13 21:22:54 server kernel:
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure
creating named object
[\_SB.PCI0._OSC.CAP> nov 13 21:22:54
server kernel: ACPI Error:
AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField
failure (20190816/dswlo> nov 13
21:22:54 server kernel: ACPI Error:
Aborting method \_SB.PCI0._OSC due to
previous error (AE_ALR> nov 13
21:22:54 server kernel: platform
INT0800:00: failed to claim resource
0: [mem 0xff800000-0xfffff> nov 13
21:22:54 server kernel: acpi
INT0800:00: platform device creation
failed: -16 nov 13 21:22:54 server
kernel: ERST: Failed to get Error Log
Address Range. nov 13 21:22:54 server
kernel: scsi target6:0:3: Wide
Transfers Fail nov 13 21:24:50 server
gdm-password][1323]: gkr-pam: unable
to locate daemon control file nov 13
21:25:16 server pulseaudio[1354]:
GetManagedObjects() failed:
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I understood the problem's cause was the graphic chip MGA G200e.
I installed the driver by this command:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga
```

Then I modified the */etc/gdm3/custom.conf* file and I uncommented the row
`#WaylandEnable=false` removing the `#` character.

Lastly I restarted the machine.